# ASP.Net/MVC - For roles there is Role Management - Is there any parallel for Feature Management?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

Is there anything already built as a library/nuget package etc. that provides for feature management in any ASP.Net/MVC application? What I am referring to as a feature is something like modules : data entry module, simple reports module, advanced report module, forecasting. 
If a user purchases a basic license, he/she gets access to only - data entry module & simple reports module.
If a user purchases a professional license, he/she gets access to - data entry module & simple reports modul & advanced report module.
If a user purchases an enterprise license, he/she gets access to all - data entry module, simple reports module, advanced report module, forecasting.

My concept that I am referring to is something that is similar to the role management concept, but not exactly the same - How a user has access a certain role and roles have access to pages/action methods.

While developing quite a few applications I have run into this scenario - User should be allowed access to a section not only because they have a particular role, but also they have purchased a certain feature in the app. NOTE: This does not boil down so simply assigning a corresponding role to the user, since a good many roles would have access to a particular feature in the application.

Also, I see a feature as time bound - having a start date and an end date (the end date is based on the period for which the user has paid for a feature), unlike role implementation in the ASP.Net Membership provider OR the simplemembership provider where there is no concept of dates with the roles.

---

### Update: What I am trying to say is that "Features" determine the number of modules you have access to in the application and the "Role" determines how much of within the module you have access to.

Is building a custom solution an alternative or is there anything readymade (free or paid) that is available out there? Just don't want to reinvent the wheel!

Thanks in advance for looking at my question.

---

Thanks for the responses thus for.

My thought was more on the lines of building something so much into the framework such that you can draw a one-to-one with how Roles work:
User.IsInRole("Admin") ==> Account.HasModule("Banking")
Similar to how the Authorization information in configured in web.config, I should be able to write:

```
<allow modules="Banking,Finanace"/>
```

Comment: I dont think there is any built in functionality for that.You can write a Custom Filter which will decide whether the requesting user has access to a particular `Controller->Action`, in which controllers can be Feature based. Or you can have regions that  seperate out different features.

Comment: Even if there was such functionality, it sounds like you have very specific needs, which means it's unlikely that any solution would fit your needs.

Comment: I had to write my own feature manager on my current project. Basically, it loads sets of partial views based on the features assigned to users. Filters and/or areas might be another option to explore if there is very little crossover in functionality between your feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any such feature is inbuilt in asp.net security/membership, but that is very easy to develop and you will not have to purchase. as this is more about how much your features/modules are independent (loosely coupled).

I think this architecture will give you basic solution:
create a table to store all modules list for which you have given licence to the client,
and on load of every module just verify that he has the proper module key stored in that table. if yes then he is allowed to use that module (then it will check for role & membership)..